Error when trying to import files across sub-folder under the same main folder
I am pretty new here and would appreciate some help.
So lately, I have been using Jupyter notebook for some learning in this case, test out function that I made from a different folder.
Originally, the structure is as follows:
/Main Folder

   / Library(containinng function)
   Notebook

In this structure I can do
     from Library."file" import "function" 

which always work
However, when I started to organise all the notebook in a folder like this
/Main Folder
    /Library
       some.py
    /Notebook
       some.ipynb

And the same import wouldn't work and return an error  Module not found: Library
So I use copilot for help which give me this snippet
import sys

# Get the path to the 'library' folder
library_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '..', 'library'))

# Append the 'library' folder to sys.path
if library_path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(library_path)

Now, when I have this, if I use the same import as mentioned, it still wouldn't work, however if I use from "file" import "function" it works just fines, which I said okay, no worries.
All of that was in Vs code. On Pycharm however I do not need to do any of them, when I use the fix that work on VsCode, Pycharm failed. So I thought there was definitely something wrong with the way the path is reach when the code cell run in Notebook
On a normal python files however, I can simply do sys.path.append(os.path.abspath".") and no matter the sub-folder, I can reach the code without error.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

this could be the reason for the path. you can try to import with an absolute path, like this from Main_Folder.Library.some import function. Also, when you use os.path.abspath make sure that you sys.path is the right path.

Thanks for the help! Your suggestion doesn't work however trying to direct Main_Folder."the directory" doesn't seem to work for me. And I don't understand what sys.path is the right path mean

Sorry, I mean using absolute path import. As you described, from Library."file" import "function" , changed to from Main_Folder.Library.some import function. Whether this can get the desired effect. Also, the path in sys.path.append(library_path) need be correct.
